# How to find power of a number in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to update the Interest field in my database. My SQL query is like as per below

> Update Table_Name set Interest  = Principal * Power(( 1 + (rate /
>   100),year)

This query works fine in MySQL but don't work with SQLite.

The error says that **No Power funcation found**

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem as I have to do this using query to update more than 3000 records at a time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a lot of functions available. But the good news is that is easy enough to add your own.

Here's how to do it using the C API (which also works from Objective-C code).

First write a power function:

```
void sqlite_power(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
    double num = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]); // get the first arg to the function
    double exp = sqlite3_value_double(argv[1]); // get the second arg
    double res = pow(num, exp);                 // calculate the result
    sqlite3_result_double(context, res);        // save the result
}
```

Then you need to register the function:

```
int res = sqlite3_create_function(dbRef, "POWER", 2, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &sqlite_power, NULL, NULL);
```

The `2` is the number of arguments for the function. `dbRef` is of course the `sqlite3 *` database reference.

Comment: Actuall Sqlite does have [`pow/power`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#pow). But you have to compile with a special flag to enable it.

Answer (score 9):

You can also create an SQLite **user-defined function** from python. Based on the example at docs.python.org: [sqlite3.Connection.create_function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function)

Create a python function:

```
def sqlite_power(x,n):
    return int(x)**n
print(sqlite_power(2,3))
# 8
```

Create a SQLite user-defined function based on the python function:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.create_function("power", 2, sqlite_power)
```

Use it:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select power(?,?)", (2,3))
print cur.fetchone()[0]
# 8
```

Comment: Thanks for this! For something so simple, I did this in a single line for brevity: `con.create_function("power", 2, lambda x, y: x**y)`.

Comment: Credit to @reokatoa, but here is an addition to avoid an OperationalError in case of null values: `con.create_function("power", 2, lambda x, y: x**y if x != None and y!=None else None )`

Answer (score 6):

I was strugginling with this too, but if all you need is powers of 2 (or multiples, etc) there is a simpler way:

Use the shift operator, e.g

```
SELECT 1 << mytable.value 

SELECT 1 << (table.x + etc..)
```

Answer (score 4):

https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p3244/installing-and-using-sqlite-extensions-on-macos-and-maybe-windows-linux-too

Step was to build the Math extensions library that some wonderful person named Liam Healy wrote:

Enter following command in terminal :

Step 1) Download/ Open link http://sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25

Step 2) Go to location where extension-functions.c is downloaded. Run command      `"gcc -fno-common -dynamiclib extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.dylib".` This will create file libsqlitefunctions.dylib at same place then you can use that in your ios application from xcode.

Now in your cocoa app you can add:

```
“SELECT load_extension(’libsqlitefunctions.dylib’);”
```

and then you have access to all kinds of glorious methods like COS, SQRT, etc! You can use them in your app like this:

```
//Activate database loading
sqlite3_enable_load_extension(database, 1);
sqlite3_load_extension(database,”libsqlitefunctions.dylib”,0,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQLite NuGet package in a .NET project, you can write an extension method and bind it at runtime;

```
[SQLiteFunction("pow", 2, FunctionType.Scalar)]
public class SQLitePowerExtension : SQLiteFunction
{
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        double num = (double)args[0];
        double exp = (double)args[1];

        return Math.Pow(num, exp);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this;

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:"))
{
    conn.Open();
    conn.BindFunction(typeof(SQLitePowerExtension).GetCustomAttribute<SQLiteFunctionAttribute>(), new SQLitePowerExtension());

    var comm = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE test (num REAL, exp REAL, result REAL)", conn);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Populate with some data - not shown

    comm = new SQLiteCommand($"UPDATE test SET result = pow(num, exp))", conn);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved with SQL. This works for integer exponents:

```
Drop Table if Exists args ;
Create Table args as Select 2.5 as Base, 4 as Exponent ;

WITH RECURSIVE pow(exponent, exponent_remainder, base, result) as (
    --FIRST EXPRESSION
    SELECT exponent,exponent -1 , base,base
    FROM args
    
    union all 
    --SECOND EXPRESSION
    select Args.exponent,pow.exponent_remainder -1, pow.base,pow.result * pow.base
    from args
    join pow on args.exponent = pow.exponent
    where pow.exponent_remainder >= 0
)
select pow.result
from pow
where pow.exponent_remainder = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually sqlite *does have* `pow/power` as a built-in mathematical function, but you need to enable it with `DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS`.

From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#pow:

> The math functions shown below are part of the SQLite amalgamation source file but are only active if the amalgamation is compiled using the -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS compile-time option.

Comment: This question was originally asked in 2012. At the time, there was no power function. The mathematical functions were not added until 2021-03-12 (version 3.35.0) which is 8 years after the question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't provide a power function or operator. You'll have to implement it yourself via [`sqlite3_create_function…`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).