# How do I perform "AS" query in django orm

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I was trying to convert this sql query into django orm query but I got stuck how do I perform sqrt and other mathematical calculation in a single ORM query.

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
  POW(69.1 * (latitude - [input_lat]), 2) +
  POW(69.1 * ([input_lng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM MyTable HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance
```

What I tried -

`MyTable.objects.extra(select={"distance": X}).extra(where=["distance > 25"]).order_by('distance')`

What should I write in place of `X`? am I going in right direction ?

if I write this

`MyTable.objects.extra(select={"distance": "SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - 37), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-122 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 573), 2))"}).extra(where=["distance > 25"]).order_by('distance')`

it throws an error, `OperationalError: no such function: SQRT`. which I guess my DB(sqlite3) doesn't support this function. how to overcome this problem?

MyTable has 5 columns including `latitude` and `longitude`.

we will get the value of `input_lat` and  `input_lng` from enduser.

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking, but have you taken a look at django-gis?

Comment: yes! I'm aware of that.

Comment: This is not Django ORM question its an sqlite question.
There are no SQRT, POW functions in sqlite.
First get your query working on sqlite console then you ask how to convert it to Djang ORM

This question might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190064/how-to-find-power-of-a-number-in-sqlite