# How do I find the value of 10 to the exponent defined by a variable in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, math, exponent

I have a column in a table and I want to find the value of 10 to the exponent defined by the values in that column.

e.g. Say, the table is called 'Table 1'. The column is called 'exponent'

Table1

Exponent

3

2

2

4

And i want to perform a mathematical operation that involves

10 ^ table1.exponent

How do I do that?

I've tried -

```
Power(10, table1.exponent)
```

But SQLite does not support the power function.

The result would be:

1000

100

100

10000

However, I don't need a table returned. I need to use these in a mathematical equation in the query.

Comment: You can register your own POWER function in SQLLite : see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13190146/8357168

Comment: Try using CTE
I tried to add an anwer, but don't know why I cant

Comment: If you're interested I've posted my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190064/how-to-find-power-of-a-number-in-sqlite/58596131#58596131

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable is an integer, how about just using a `case` expression:

```
select (case exponent
            when 0 then 1
            when 1 then 10
            when 2 then 100
            when 3 then 1000
            when 4 then 10000
            when 5 then 100000
            when 6 then 1000000
            when 7 then 10000000
            when 8 then 100000000
        end)
```

Adding a `power()` function is definitely more versatile, but this might work for your specific need.