# Android Studio SQLiteOpenHelper: how to find POW() of a number

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to get the power of a number in SQLite Android studio, but seems pow() is not supported in sqlite just like mysql.

I find this:
[How to find power of a number in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190064/how-to-find-power-of-a-number-in-sqlite)
but it's confusing and I don't think there's an answer I can apply in Android.

Just want it like this but there's an error in POW() function:

```
Select a.* from Table a where number=Pow(inputnumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String qry = "Select a.* from Table a where number="+Math.pow(inputnumber,pwr)
```

OR try to use

```
Select a.* from Table a where number=power(inputnumber,pwr)
```

Comment: yes i could do it like that but, I mean is there other way? like i have cases that also needs to be like this:  Pow(tablecolumn)

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html I can see pow() function is listed in SQLite

Comment: you can use new version of SQLite either download aar file from official site or from jetpack https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/sqlite

Comment: @Pillowsky examples of using columns the **activity** table has a column named **related_stock** `SELECT power(related_stock,5), related_stock FROM activity;` is a pretty simple example. Could be more complicated such as `SELECT power(related_stock,(SELECT max(related_stock) / 5 FROM activity)), (SELECT max(related_stock) / 5 FROM activity) as calculated_power, related_stock FROM activity;` Where the power is derived from a table (same one in this case).